# Formatando campo data com jQuery Masked Input

Tags: jquery, data

Caros, procurei e testei de diversas formas como formatar um campo data no jQuery mas não está funcionando.

Já importei o [jQuery Masked Input](http://plugins.jquery.com/maskedinput/) no JSP:

```jsp
src='<%=renderResponse.encodeURL(renderRequest.getContextPath()
                        + "/js/jquery/jquery.maskedinput-1.2.2.js")%>'>
```

Meu campo data:

```html
<td align="right">Data Inicial:</td>
<td class="form_text"><input type="text" name="dataInicial" id="dataInicial">
```

E a função jQuery assim:

```js
jQuery(function($){
   $("#dataInicial").mask("99/99/9999");
});
```

Alguém pode me dizer se estou comendo bola em algum lugar?

Comment: Tente simplificar, desta forma: `jQuery("#dataInicial").mask("99/99/9999");`

Comment: Funcionou cara!!!!!!!! Muito Obrigado Oeslei.......

Comment: Já verificou se o script está realmente sendo importado ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O que acontece é que você não recebe o objeto jQuery na variável `$`, pois o valor dela está vindo como um parâmetro pela função e não diretamente do objeto `window` como normalmente acontece. Utilizar diretamente a função jQuery resolve o problema:

```
jQuery("#dataInicial").mask("99/99/9999");
```

Ou então, passar o jQuery como parâmetro para a função:

```
(function($) {
    $("#dataInicial").mask("99/99/9999");
)(jQuery);
```

Comment: Sem querer abusar, como ficaria a validação para verificar se o campo foi preenchido corretamente utilizando também o jQuery?

Comment: Há várias formas. Você pode fazer a validação na mão ou utilizar um plugin. Não é tão fácil, mas também não é difícil. Conteúdo na internet não falta. Você pode inclusive procurar por [plugins de validação](http://plugins.jquery.com/?s=validation) no próprio site do jquery =)

Answer (score 1):

Estou usando do `mask` no contato dessa minha plataforma [aqui](http://ipupo.com.br/CursosOnline). Fiz o teste adicionando seu `input` e com o script abaixo, fiz funcionar regularmente em localhost.

Tentei colocar o exemplo no JSFIDDLE, mas tive problemas com as referências externas.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#dataInicial").mask("99/99/9999");
});
```

Se não funcionar, verifique a ordem de importação do script e do jQuery, além de via Chrome visualizar os elementos importados.
Para isso, siga as seguintes instruções: Pressione F12 > Clique em Network > Atualize a Página

Tudo o que não for encontrado ficará vermelho.

Além disso você pode verificar a falta de integridade de scripts via Console. Para isso,  aperte F12 e depois ESC.